# How to add remove functionality to my todo app?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Jsfiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/adityatrips/y4L36p0g/)

```
const btnTodo = document.querySelector('.btnTodo');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todoList');
const removeBtn = document.querySelector('.btnRemove');

btnTodo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var todoText = txtTodo.value.trim();
    var listItem = document.createElement('p');
    listItem.innerHTML = todoText + '&nbsp;<button class="btn btnRemove"><i class="big fas fa-trash"></i></button>' + '<br>';
    todoList.append(listItem);
    txtTodo.innerText = null;
});

removeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //WHAT TO DO??
});
```

I am in high school. I wanted to include a remove functionality to my todo app. I made this by the knowledge given to me by my school.

Comment: What are you stuck on, in particular?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so there are various ways of doing this, here's one of the ways:

```
let txtTodo = document.querySelector('.txtTodo');
let btnTodo = document.querySelector('.btnTodo');
let todoList = document.querySelector('.todoList');

btnTodo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let todoText = txtTodo.value.trim();
    let listItem = document.createElement('p');
    listItem.innerHTML = todoText + '&nbsp;<button class="btn btnRemove"><i class="big fas fa-trash"></i></button>' + '<br>';
    todoList.append(listItem);
    txtTodo.innerText = null;

    listItem.querySelector('.btnRemove').addEventListener("click", () => {
        listItem.remove()
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5thzg17/1/)

One thing to keep in mind is that storing all remove buttons in a variable beforehand (as you attempted in line 3) isn't going to work because is isn't a live collection and thus when you append new buttons in the DOM then the stored collection would become stale. Hence it's a good idea to add event listeners to newly appended elements as I did above.

Also you should be doing `txtTodo.value = "";` instead of `txtTodo.innerText = null;` to clear the input.

Good luck!

Comment: TanQ WebDev Expert

Comment: @AxityaTripathi Haha you're welcome! Happy to help!